# Classes post migrate from magento1x

Tags: magento2

What are the **equivalent classes** for the below in **Magento2** ?

Does Magento2 core uses these classes? If so in which class can i find them ?

```
Mage_Adminhtml_System_Convert_GuiController 

Mage_ImportExport_Adminhtml_ImportController

Mage_Catalog_Model_Convert_Adapter_Product

Mage_Dataflow_Model_Convert_Adapter_Io

Mage_Api_Model_Resource_Abstract

Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
```

If not, how to extend these classes from my custom classes?